# Why is my program not reading the first line of code in the referenced file(fileName)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-languages

```
def main():
    read()

def read():

    fileName=input("Enter the file you want to count: ")

    infile=open(fileName , "r")
    text=infile.readline()
    count=0
    while text != "":

        text=str(count)     
        count+=1
        text=infile.readline()



        print(str(count)+ ": " + text)

    infile.close()     
main()
```

-the referenced .txt file has only two elements

44

33

-the output of this code should look like

1: 44

2: 33

-my output is

1: 33

2:

im not sure why the program is not picking up the first line in the referenced .txt file. The line numbers are correct however 33 should be second to 44.

Comment: `text=infile.readline()` You read it before loop and then inside the loop. So the line read before loop is lost.

Comment: that makes sense, should i add text=infile.readline()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is explained in the comments:

```
def main():
    read()

def read():
    fileName=input("Enter the file you want to count: ")
    infile=open(fileName , "r")
    text=infile.readline()  ##Reading the first line here but not printing
    count=0
    while text != "":
      text=str(count)     
      count+=1
      text=infile.readline() ##Reading the 2nd line here
      print(str(count)+ ": " + text) ##Printing the 2nd line here, missed the first 
                                     ##line

    infile.close()     


main()
```

Modify the program as:

```
def main():
   read()

def read():
   fileName= input("Enter the file you want to count: ")
   infile = open(fileName , "r")
   text = infile.readline()
   count = 1                             # Set count to 1
   while text != "":
      print(str(count)+ ": " + str(text))   # Print 1st line here
      count = count + 1                     # Increment count to 2 
      text = infile.readline()              # Read 2nd line 

   infile.close()                           # Close the file


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    read()

def read():

    fileName=input("Enter the file you want to count: ")

    with open(fileName,'r') as f:
        print('\n'.join([' : '.join([str(i+1),v.rstrip()]) for i,v in enumerate(f.readlines())]))
main()
```

Comment: I find your answer the most straightforward because you’re still reading the whole document anyways

Answer (score 0):

I'm very confused by your read function. You start by reading the first line into text:

```
text=infile.readline()
```

Presumable at this point text contains `44`.

You then immediately demolish this value before you've done anything with it by overwriting it with:

```
text = str(count)
```

ie you read two lines before printing anything at all.

Comment: yeah that seems to be an unnecessary line of code (text=str(count)), any way to fix this and read from line 0?

Answer (score 0):

You should print the value of `text` before you overwrite it with the next `readline`.

Simply move the `print` statement before `readline`:

```
while text != "":

    count+=1
    print(str(count)+ ": " + text)
    text=infile.readline()
```

Comment: text=str(count) is a line of code serving no purpose here, your suggestion was correct though

Comment: Indeed. Removed as suggested.